# Nginx is not serving my django app media files

Tags: django, nginx

I am new at django, and I recently sent my django app to production. On my website, I can only see static files, but media are different story. I have tried for three days to solve this issue but without luck. The following are my settings and nginx set up:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myIP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/make/leosblog;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

I have noticed while inspecting  the html, that media files' path start with '/media/media/...', however, all my media files are inside only one media folder. Not sure if this is the cause for this problem.

What can I do to solve this issue? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR` - is this correct? Because this means that your media files are stored in your main project directory. Another thing, your Nginx conf doesn't have a `/media/` location for serving media files.

Comment: Well my media files are stored inside the media folder which is in my main directory. It has worked like that before sending my app to production. Not sure if it should be like that, tho. And, yes, I didn't know that I had to add a /media/ location. I'll give it a try. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

add location of media folder in nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myIP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/make/leosblog;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root /media_path;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

then add to the urls.py file following code:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_ROOT, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Good answer. There's one thing I'd like to point out is that you don't need to add anything to the urls.py. Because all the static and media files will be served by Nginx directly, so any requests starting with `/static` or `/media` will never reach Django. Besides, if `DEBUG` is set to `False` in production environment, Django will not serve static files. So, it's pointless to add anything to urls.py.

Comment: Nope. Have you ever test it? static folder is in the scope of django program. then if you want access to that, must be requested to django

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I have not been able to solve my issue. Maybe I didn't provide you guys with the whole scope of my problem.

The templates that display the media files are inside an app that I called "posts". I am using the include() function to pass the urls from my project main folder to my posts app folder. Where should I add the urlpatterns? In both of my urls.py? or only in my project main folder urls.py?

Comment: Moreover, my project directory goes like this:

leosblog

Comment: Moreover, my project directory goes like this:

leosblog
  accounts(app)
  leosblog (project main folder)
  media
  posts
  sitepages
  static
  venv

I added the following path to my nginx settings for my media folder: 

    location   /media/ {
          root  /home/make/leosblog;
    }

Am I adding the right path? This root seems ok since it is the right one in my server. However, I still cannot make media files display in production.

Comment: Can you display tree directory of main folders

Comment: @MohammadAli Yes, I've tested it. I'm not making things up. Besides, it's **obvious** from the Nginx configuration file that urls with `/static` and `/media` are being served directly by Nginx, so those requests will never reach Django backend. *`"static folder is in the scope of django program. then if you want access to that, must be requested to django"`* - wrong. Django doesn't serve static files in production. So any requests accessing static files are outright ignored by Django. In fact, **that is why Nginx is required - to serve static files because Django doesn't**. How's that confusin